# Dependency injection, inject with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using vNext implementation of DI.
How to pass parameters to constructor?
For example, i have class:

```
public class RedisCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public RedisCacheProvider(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    //interface methods implementation...
}
```

And service register:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider, RedisCacheProvider>();
```

How to pass parameter to constructor of RedisCacheProvider class?
For example for Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<RedisCacheProvider>()
       .As<ICacheProvider>()
       .WithParameter("connectionString", "myPrettyLocalhost:6379");
```

Comment: My generic solution: https://gist.github.com/ReallyLiri/c669c60db2109554d5ce47e03613a7a9

Comment: Related post - [.NET Core DI, ways of passing parameters to constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53884417/465053)

Comment: Note that a connection string is generally considered configuration (and, in fact, often a secret because it may contain user names and passwords). So the "correct" way to handle this is to depend on IConfiguration and get it from there (e.g. using "redisCache::connectionString" as key). Then you just need to configure a value, either in appsettings.json, or in the project secrets (or in whatever other configuration store is in use).

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can either provide a delegate to manually instantiate your cache provider or directly provide an instance:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider>(provider => new RedisCacheProvider("myPrettyLocalhost:6379"));

services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider>(new RedisCacheProvider("myPrettyLocalhost:6379"));
```

Please note that the container will not explicitly dispose of manually instantiated types, even if they implement IDisposable. See the ASP.NET Core doc about [Disposal of Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#disposal-of-services) for more info.

Comment: Simple and Useful

Comment: Don't forget if your service takes other parameters you have registered, you can pass a reference to your service when it is registered.  e.g. if "RedisCacheProvider" also required ISomeService, you'd do this:  services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider>(provider => new RedisCacheProvider("myPrettyLocalhost:6379", provider.GetService<ISomeService>()));

Comment: @KévinChalet it would be good if you would specify in your answer that "manually instantiated types" is *solely* about registering types through `AddSingleton<T>(T)`. Types returned from registered delegates (e.g. using `AddSingleton<T>(Func<IServiceProvider, T>)`) will in fact be disposed of.

Comment: How do I go about handling this if I have another implementation of the ICacheProvider?

Answer (score 45):

If the constructur also has dependencies that should be resolved by DI you can use that:

```cs
public class RedisCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly IMyInterface _myImplementation;

    public RedisCacheProvider(string connectionString, IMyInterface myImplementation)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _myImplementation = myImplementation;
    }
    //interface methods implementation...
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyInterface>();
services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider>(provider => 
    RedisCacheProvider("myPrettyLocalhost:6379", provider.GetService<IMyInterface>()));
```

Comment: What if the class is not a singleton? Also, what if you can't directly instantiate the class because its constructor takes other parameters from DI? Something like `public class ManyObjects(SomeDbContext fromDI1, SomeClass fromDI2, string stringArg)`? The only way I can think of it is making a class like `class StringArgForManyObject` and add it as a singleton to the DI, but its cumbersome. Is there any better way? (the `stringArgs` is the same for all instances of `ManyObjects` within the app instance, but it can vary between different app instances).

Answer (score 22):

You can use :

```
 services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider>(x =>
      ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<RedisCacheProvider>(x, "myPrettyLocalhost:6379"));
```

Dependency Injection : ActivatorUtilities will inject any dependencies to your class.

Here is the link to the MS docs: [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance)

Also: See [@poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52645270/754485) for more information. Basically it pulls from the provided services and any other params you pass, like a composit constructor.

Answer (score 13):

You can use something like the example code below.

Manager class:

```
public class Manager : IManager
{
    ILogger _logger;
    IFactory _factory;
    public Manager(IFactory factory, ILogger<Manager> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _factory = factory;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IFactory, Factory>(sp =>
    {
        var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Factory>>();
        var dbContext = sp.GetRequiredService<MyDBContext>();
        return new Factory(dbContext, logger);
    });
    services.AddTransient<IManager, Manager>(sp =>
    {
        var factory = sp.GetRequiredService<IFactory>();
        var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Manager>>();
        return new Manager(factory, logger);
    });
}
```

You can read the full example here: [DI in Startup.cs in .Net Core](http://dotnet-concept.com/Articles/2020/7/5800891/Getting-started-with-Dependency-Injection-in-Startup-cs-in-Net-Core)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but you could DI inject a factory that creates and exposes an instance of your provider class.