# Multiple dependency injections for same class C# and .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have an interface

```
public interface ITest
{
    void SayHello();
}
```

And it's implemented as

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    Test(string type)
    {
        // Do Something with type
    }

    public void SayHello()
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

Register it in the DI as:

```
services.AddScoped<ITest, Test>();
```

I need to create two instance with these conditions:

```
Test t1 = new Test("ABC");
Test t2 = new Test("XYZ");
```

How I can achieve this using DI?

Comment: https://medium.com/null-exception/factory-pattern-using-built-in-dependency-injection-of-asp-net-core-f91bd3b58665

Comment: This completely depends on the meaning of the strings `ABC` and `XYZ` in your application and where they are coming from. Are they coming from the config file, and thus constant for the duration of the running application, and there just two `Test` 'registrations'? Or represent these two strings runtime data, coming from a database, or web request, and do you have other `Test` instances at runtime? Please update your post with answers to this question. Based on this information we can supply you with a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

With this exact use-case in mind, DI provides the following method:  `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`
(*note the use of `ITest` vs `Test`*)

```
Test t1 = 
    ActivatorUtilities
        .CreateInstance<Test>("ABC");

Test t2 = 
    ActivatorUtilities
        .CreateInstance<Test>("XYZ");
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several options how you can implement it.

### 1. Factory

Create a factory for generating the instance you need:

```cs
public TestFactory : ITestFactory
{
   public ITest Create(string type)
   {
       return new Test(type);
   }
}
```

And register just the factory

```cs
services.AddScoped<ITestFactory, TestFactory>();
```

Advantage you have the single piece of code the `ITestFactory` which can be mocked and the whole logic how the instance and which instance is create resides there.

### 2. List of implementations

Register them all as `ITest`

```cs
services.AddScoped<ITest>(sp => new Test("ABC"));
services.AddScoped<ITest>(sp => new Test("XYZ"));
```

... and then use it in a class like this:

```cs
public class Consumer 
{
   public Consumer(IEnumerable<ITest> testInstances)
   {
       // This is working great if it does not matter what the instance is and you just need to use all of them.
   }
}
```

### 3. ActivatorUtilities

... or just use the `ActivatorUtilities` which is a way to create the instance directly from a `IServiceProvider` [see Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) or this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644507/using-activatorutilities-createinstance-to-create-instance-from-type)

```cs
var serviceProvider = <yourserviceprovider>;
var test1 = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Test>(sp, "ABC");
var test2 = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Test>(sp, "XYZ");
```

But like it is also written in the comment of your question it really depends what you want to do with both instances and where do you get the `string type` from.

You can also do more advanced ways with a combination of option 1 and 2 but therefore the better description of your problem and usage is needed.

Comment: What if Test aslo have ILogger<Test>  to be injected as parameter? How do you inject it into for example 2. List of implementations?

Comment: you can use: ```services.AddScoped<ITest>(sp => new Test("ABC", sp.GetService<ILogger<Test>()));``` to accomplish this if needed