Blazor Server, Scoped service seem to be instantiated for each page (or what am I doing wrong?)
I am pretty new to Blazor, and are building a small Blazor Server application in Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 8.0. I am going to use a Scoped service to keep data within one browser tab session, i.e. "circuit".
The problem I experience is that my Scoped service keep getting instantiated for each Blazor page separately.
What I have done:

Create a Blazor Server project with the test pages

Created my service in TestService.cs
namespace BlazorAppScoped.Model
{
    public interface ITestService
    {
        string GetDateTimeStart();
    }

    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        private DateTime _DateTimeStart;

        public TestService() 
        {
            _DateTimeStart = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public string GetDateTimeStart()
        {
            return _DateTimeStart.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        }
    }
}


Register the service in Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();


Injecting the service in the various pages where I need to access it:
@inject ITestService testService



The problem is that when I navigate between the pages, the constructor of the TestService gets called each time. The whole purpose of scoped is to have one instance throughout the App.
If I change step 3 to AddSingleton instead, it works as expected for a Singleton, i.e. there is only one instantiation throughput multiple sessions and multiple tabs.
What am I doing wrong, so that the Scoped does not work as intended?

Thanks for the reply, yes I know the difference between Transient, Scoped, Singleton. My problem is that it acts exactly as Transient, even though I use AddScoped.

Sorry, I should have been clearer. (I could also be wrong.) But I believe each blazor page is a new request. So would come with a new scoped instance.

What template options did you choose?  Interactivity mode and interactivity location?  If you are creating new instances of a scoped service on each page then you are creating new SPA sessions on each request.

@IAmGroot https://stackoverflow.com/q/76195106/11683

@GSerg . Thanks, im not familiar with Blazor, so wasnt 100% sure.

The thing is that it works fine for Singleton. Its just that Scoped and Transient behaves in exactly the same way....

scoped is to have one instance throughout the App no, that's the Singleton. In Blazor Server, the scope is the user circuit, essentially the user session. If your service is scooped, a new instance will be created for every user

@Tommy: and Singleton behaves very differently between Blazor Server and Blazor Wasm. So be careful.

and .NET 8.0 in Blazor 8 there's no clear distinction between WASM and Server. In the same project some pages can be static, client, server or auto-rendered. In the blazor template the default is static and changes in each page based on an attribute You'll have to post enough code so people can reproduce the issue. I suspect you added the component to a static non-prerendered page, so the scope is essentially the page request. If the page was pre-rendered (in which case the server just returns the rendered page), the service would be created once during prerendering

Solved by adding <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" /> in App.razor. Very thankful for all your replies!

You didn't tell us what Interactivity mode(s) you selected.
The default is Static rendering, that behaves as an MVC or Razor page: each request (page view) is a Scope. Your service is already disposed when your user sees the page.
You should already see a different behavior in the Counter page, it is Interactive. When you change to that mode globally you should get more or less what you want.
Change the line in App.razor to
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

Prerendering is on by default so that will produce extra copies of your Service.

Thanks for the reply Henk, I have tested various. For example @rendermode InteractiveServer. However, does this really matter for this Scoped question? I believe I am doing something wrong, however, I do not understand what.

Well, the lifetime of a Scope is very different for the various modes. Static rendering has the shortest.

And static is the default in the blazor template

Thank you so much Henk, when I added the line <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" /> in the App.razor, it started to work as I want! Surprisingly, the Interactivity setting in each page seem not to have any effect. I had to add it globally to take effect. Again, very grateful for everyone's kind help!

Hey guys. In my application I need to use InteractiveAuto. How can I achieve that my scoped service will be created once user starts the app and during this session only this instance of the service will be used?


What am I doing wrong

I'm not sure, but here's a demo showing it working as advertised.  I use a Guid to track service instances.
Template: Blazor InteractiveServer with Global interactivity.
   public class ScopedService
   {
       public Guid Id { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

       public ScopedService()
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"Service created with ID:{this.Id.ToString()}");
       }
   }

Registered as
builder.Services.AddScoped<ScopedService>();

In each page:
@page "/"
@inject ScopedService ScopedService
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code{

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name} Initialized with Service id: {ScopedService.Id.ToString()}");
    }
}

What you get:
=> Pre Render
Service created with ID:42688bcf-d3cc-4b58-a465-9d303757f6f0
Home Initialized with Service id: 42688bcf-d3cc-4b58-a465-9d303757f6f0
==> SPA session start
Service created with ID:8bc0a22a-9a1b-4d5d-8715-acc7921854ef
Home Initialized with Service id: 8bc0a22a-9a1b-4d5d-8715-acc7921854ef
Counter Initialized with Service id: 8bc0a22a-9a1b-4d5d-8715-acc7921854ef
Weather Initialized with Service id: 8bc0a22a-9a1b-4d5d-8715-acc7921854ef

The initial service instance created [and destroyed] in the Pre-Render HttpRequest context, and then the second instance created on first use in the Blazor SPA context and the same instance used by all the components.

Store the value in Local Storage and use the same value till your app is running. For this you need to add Blazored.LocalStorage package.
The detail you can find here : https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage

If you want to keep the data even when refresh the tab. You could use Browser session storage.
I recommand you use Blazored.Session storage. Just be careful, it doesn't work for SSR. So you will need to set the global rendermode disable SSR in App.razor like
<Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false)" />

Then you could make a simple test like following:
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();

@page "/"
@inject Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService session
<button @onclick="test">test</button>
@code{
    private async Task  test (){
        await session.SetItemAsStringAsync("key1", "value1");
    }
}

You will find the value will be only saved for the tab that you click the button.

Reference : https://github.com/Blazored/SessionStorage

You're confusing Blazor with ASP.NET Core. In Blazor Server the scope is the entire user circuit, not the (non-existent) request. What you posted as reference isn't a reference nor has anything to do with the question. It's a package used to store data in the browser's session storage

The actual reference is the Service Lifetime section in the ASP.NET Core Blazor dependency injection page

SessionStorage could be a good alternative to a Scoped service. At least it works across all render modes except Static.
