# How to use singleton in asp.net core 2.1 with parameter (interface)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, singleton

In Starup file

```
services.AddScoped<IUserResponsitory , UserResponsitory>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthService>(service=>new AuthServiceImpl(
            service.GetService<IUserResponsitory>(),service.GetService<IConfiguration>()));
```

In AuthServiceImpl file:

```
    private IUserResponsitory m_userResponsitory;
    private IConfiguration m_config;
    public  AuthServiceImpl(IUserResponsitory userResponsitory, IConfiguration config) 
    {
        m_config = config;
        m_userResponsitory = userResponsitory;
    }
```

In the UserResponsitory file.

```
public class UserResponsitory : Responsitory<Users>,IUserResponsitory
    {
        private DbSet<Users> userEntity;

        public UserResponsitory(MyDBContext context) : base(context)
        {
            userEntity = context.Set<Users>();
        }
    }
```

The error below
[image]

Some of the help:
[help1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834295/dependency-injection-inject-with-parameters)

[help2](https://cmatskas.com/net-core-dependency-injection-with-constructor-parameters-2/)

Can you help me.Please!

Answer (score 0):

Since scope validation is applied by .NET Core, you can not resolve services with scoped lifetime (IUserResponsitory in your case) in the constructor of a service registered with singleton lifetime (IAuthService).

So you need to change your IAuthService lifetime to scoped.

`services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();`

Useful Resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#scope-validation

https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2019/02/aspnet-core-scope-validation.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so the  Scoped lifetime services are just created once per request.I want to create the Singleton for my service where save my token when using login. If I used the  Scoped  for that service , I wouldn't found the token created before.

Comment: So making your IAuth service as singleton means that data will be shared across among users logging in which you will never desire.

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, you could not resolve a scoped service from `root provider`.

If you prefer use `IAuthService` as `Singleton`, you could reolve the service from `IServiceProvider` like

1. `Startup.cs`

   ```
   services.AddScoped<IUserResponsitory , UserResponsitory>();
   services.AddSingleton<IAuthService, AuthServiceImpl>();
   ```
2. `AuthServiceImpl`

   ```
   public class AuthService : IAuthService
   {
       private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
       private readonly IConfiguration m_config;
       public AuthService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider
           , IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
           m_config = configuration;
       }

       public void Auth()
       {
           using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
           {
               var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserResponsitory>();
               var result = db.Users.ToList();
           }
       }
   }
   ```