# How to register a class in C# that has another dependency and also accepts parameters in the constructor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a class in c# that takes in 2 parameters: dependency on MongoDB database and a string variable denoting the name of the collection in the DB. How can I register this class in `Program.cs`?

My `MongoRepository` class:

```
namespace Play.Catalog.Service.Repositories
{
    public class MongoRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: IEntity
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<T> dbCollection;

        private readonly FilterDefinitionBuilder<T> filterBuilder = Builders<T>.Filter;

        public MongoRepository(IMongoDatabase database, string collectionName)
        {
            dbCollection = database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
        }
...
}
```

I am using .net6

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834295/dependency-injection-inject-with-parameters

Comment: @Nahid In that question there's only a string as a parameter, but in my case I also have a DI in the `MongoRepository` class which makes it difficult to call this cass from `Program.cs`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService>(conf => 
new MyService(conf.GetRequiredService<IMongoDatabase>(),
configuration.GetValue<string>("CollectionName")));
```

Comment: How to fetch `configuration ` from Program.cs?

Comment: var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args) and var configuration = builder.Configuration;